# How do I pass a prop into a react-router Route?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication, react-router-v4

I'm trying to learn react router (v4) in depth by building a simple app with firebase, what i am doing is when a user login with google using firebase they will be redirected to another component and when they go to the root path again '/' they will no longer see the login ( i am doing this by redirecting based on state )

I have two problems

My first problem is on successful authentication the user will be redirected to the /dashboard as expected but if i go back or type the root path again the login page will be shown briefly and then redirect.. i think because my method is not fast enough which is the `componentWillMount();`

My second problem is i want to pass in some props to the dashboard but i don't know how, i've been looking and searching in the internet but i have no idea how to implement it...

this is my login.js, i want to pass the currentUser to dashboard and also when user goes back to the login path and if they are logged in i want to redirect them fast enough without showing the login page...

```
  state = {
        currentUser: null,
        successLogin: false
    }

    googleAuth = () => {
        auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(response => {
            const token = response.credential.accessToken;
            const currentUser = response.user;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.code , 'occured');
        })
    }

    // firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    //   var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    //   var user = result.user;
    // }).catch(function(error) {
    //   var errorCode = error.code;
    //   var errorMessage = error.message;
    //   var email = error.email;
    //   var credential = error.credential;
    // });

    componentDidMount() {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user) {
                console.log('a user was successfuly logged in')
                this.setState({
                    currentUser: user.displayName,
                    successLogin: true
                })
            } else {
                console.log('eerror')
            }
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if(this.state.successLogin){
            this.props.history.replace("/dashboard");
        } else {
            console.log('not a successful login');
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if(this.state.successLogin){
            <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
        }
    }
```

here is my dashboard im creating new state for the user since i don't know how to get the currentUser state from the login...

```
 state = {
        user: null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
       auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            this.setState({
                user: user.displayName
            })
       })
    }
    render(){
        const { user } = this.state;
        return (
            <h1> DashBoard {user}</h1>
            )
    }
}
```

this is my routes.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Login} />
            <Route path='/register' component={Register} /> 
            <Route path='/dashboard' component={MainDashBoard} />
          </Switch>
      </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I know that i can use redux but i don't want to jump into redux yet....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `.onAuthStateChanged` code in a `componentDidMount` method in your routes file as opposed to your dashboard and your login page. If your routes file is the lowest common ancestor of the dashboard and login components then handle authentication there and pass down the user as a prop to each route. Handle redirections based on props as opposed to authenticating in both components. You can't place props directly into the `<Route/>` component so you'll have to write a public or private Routes higher order component and merge the props in as a replacement route component.

I usually just pop these at the bottom of my routes file, or you could store them in a file of their own and import them.

```
const renderMergedProps = (component, ...rest) => {
  const finalProps = Object.assign({}, ...rest)
  return React.createElement(component, finalProps)
}

const PublicRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps => {
        return renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest)
      }}
    />
  )
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component, authed, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps =>
        authed === true ? (
          renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest)
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: routeProps.location } }}
          />
        )}
    />
  )
}
```

Now you can use these higher order components in place of the `<Router/>` component but with your user prop merged in (or you could use an `authed` boolean prop to show if someone is logged in or not instead of having to pass the entire user object down, set an `authed` boolean in state and turn it to true when `onAuthStateChanged` registers a user).

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <div>
          <Switch>
            <PublicRoute
              exact 
              path='/' 
              component={Login}   
              authed={this.state.authed} />
            <PrivateRoute
              path="/dashboard"
              component={MainDashBoard}
              user={this.state.user}
            />
          </Switch>
      </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: It seems a lot more complicated than it actually is. Don't let this intimidate you. Please continue with your router learnings, don't go down the hoc rabbit hole till you find yourself repeating chunks of code a lot. Routing is a foundation you should be comfortable with long before your optimising things with hocs.

Comment: I found a much much simpler way to do this. For a public route, you can use a render prop. Let's say you want to pass the number 5 into a Landing page route. ```<Route
            exact
            path='/landing'
            render={props => <LandingPage {...props} count={5} />}
          />``` BOOM!